How to change Neovim LSP configuration schema/settings?
I am trying to override the default LSP configuration schema for pyright within neovim. I have installed my lsps using Mason and Mason-lspconfig and am using the recommended setup from LSP-zero. The lsp is working perfectly and correctly giving autocompletion and errors. While it is working fine, I was hoping to override some of its default behaviors such as reportIncompatibleMethodOveride. I have looked through the pyright documentation and know this can be done by re-assigning this variable to false or "warning". Unfortunately, I am not how to actually change these settings. I have included a screenshot with two ways I have tried to change this value, and while I am not getting any lua errors when running this config, I am still getting reportIncompatibleMethodOveride error messages.
If anyone can help me understand how to properly format the change to the default schema that would be great.



EDIT: Here is the current section of config code in plaintext for those that wanted it:
require("mason").setup({})
require("mason-lspconfig").setup({
    -- Replace the language servers listed here
    -- with the ones you want to install
    ensure_installed = { "pyright", "tsserver", "rust_analyzer" },
    handlers = {
        function(server_name)
            require("lspconfig")[server_name].setup({})
        end,

        -- this is the "custom handler" for `tsserver`
        tsserver = function()
            require("lspconfig").tsserver.setup({
                single_file_support = false,
                on_init = function(client)
                    -- disable formatting capabilities
                    client.server_capabilities.documentFormattingProvider = false
                    client.server_capabilities.documentFormattingRangeProvider = false
                end,
            })
        end,

        -- python defaults:
        pyright = function()
            require("lspconfig").pyright.setup({
                settings = {
                    reportIncompatibleMethodOveride = false,
                    python = {
                        analysis = {
                            reportIncompatibleMethodOveride = false,
                        },
                    },
                },
            })
        end,
    },
})


Please ensure that the code and error era posted in text format, and not as a screenshot.
